# Error: invalid syntax in INSERT INTO statement (using postgresql and django)

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to make my database to make a jeopardy style game. I've made my app's model and migrated it in django, and am now trying to populate the database using a python program. However, I'm getting an error in the INSERT INTO statement, with the carat pointing to the 'O' in into. What's also strange is that if I copy and paste the insert into statement and first statement of data and paste them while I'm in the database shell, the insert works no problem. Could someone please tell me what could be the problem here?

Edit: I'm only trying to do this with a python file because when I run question1.sql (detailed below) I got the same error, so I thought this might be the issue. I was able to run questions1.sql and populate an empty database not created with django.

[Successful insertion in database shell]:

```
jeopardy=# INSERT INTO game_clues (episode, airdate, round, category, worth, clue, answer) VALUES
jeopardy-# ('4680','2004-12-31','Jeopardy!','HISTORY','$200','For the last 8 years of his life\, Galileo was under house arrest for espousing this man''s theory','Copernicus');
INSERT 0 1
jeopardy=# delete from game_clues where episode = '4680';
DELETE 1
jeopardy=# exit
postgres@ip-172-26-0-21:~$ exit
logout
```

[Error message]:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-26-0-21:~/Jeopardy$ python3 questions1.py
  File "questions1.py", line 9
    insert_query = INSERT INTO game_clues (episode, airdate, round, category, worth, clue, answer) VALUES
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[My python file] (first few lines of data, there are many more):

```
import psycopg2
connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "postgres",
                                  password = "Jasper",
                                  host = "localhost",
                                  port = "5432",
                                  database = "jeopardy")
cur = connection.cursor()

insert_query = INSERT INTO game_clues (episode, airdate, round, category, worth, clue, answer) VALUES
('4680','2004-12-31','Jeopardy!','HISTORY','$200','For the last 8 years of his life\, Galileo was under house arrest for espousing this man''s theory','Copernicus'),
('4680','2004-12-31','Jeopardy!','ESPN''s TOP 10 ALL-TIME ATHLETES','$200','No. 2: 1912 Olympian; football star at Carlisle Indian School; 6 MLB seasons with the Reds\, Giants & Braves','Jim Thorpe'),
('4680','2004-12-31','Jeopardy!','EVERYBODY TALKS ABOUT IT...','$200','The city of Yuma in this state has a record average of 4\,055 hours of sunshine each year','Arizona'),
```

SQL file when run with python3:

```
INSERT INTO game_clues (episode, airdate, round, category, worth, clue, answer) VALUES
('4680','2004-12-31','Jeopardy!','HISTORY','$200','For the last 8 years of his life\, Galileo was under house arrest for espousing this man''s theory','Copernicus'),
('4680','2004-12-31','Jeopardy!','ESPN''s TOP 10 ALL-TIME ATHLETES','$200','No. 2: 1912 Olympian; football star at Carlisle Indian School; 6 MLB seasons with the Reds\, Giants & Braves','Jim Thorpe'),
('4680','2004-12-31','Jeopardy!','EVERYBODY TALKS ABOUT IT...','$200','The city of Yuma in this state has a record average of 4\,055 hours of sunshine each year','Arizona'),
```

error message when running sql file:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-26-0-21:~/Jeopardy$ python3 questions1.sql
  File "questions1.sql", line 1
    INSERT INTO game_clues (episode, airdate, round, category, worth, clue, answer) VALUES
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: shouldn't `insert_query` be a string? Like `insert_query = "INSERT INTO game_clues..."`

Comment: @narendra-choudhary I'm not quite sure, but even when I just run it as a sql file I get the same error. I'll edit the post for clarity

Comment: The SyntaxError is most likely because of your query not being a string. -> `insert_query = "INSERT INTO ...` should work and prevent the given syntax-error. If the query itself isn't working, please open a new question, because this would be a different error.

Comment: You cannot do `python3 questions1.sql`. You cannot run SQL file with Python. Compiler will consider it a Python file, and you'll get the same error. [Just put quotes around `INSERT INTO...` in your Python code](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Comment: The syntax should be `INSERT INTO game_clues (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...);`  where `col1` etc are the column or field names in the table and `val1` etc are the values that you wish to insert.  You can skip declaring the column names if you're populating _all_ the columns, otherwise they must be declared, and the number of cols declared must equal the number of vals provided.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I needed the quotes around the literal, and was also having issues with multi-line quotes. Sorry for asking such a dumb question lol, I've never tried python with SQL before

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, I needed quotes around my string literal. I also needed to make them triple quotes as I had a multi-line string.